# Separate JSON and non-JSON logs with jq?

Tags: json, jq, tee

I have some log files which contain mixed of JSON and non-JSON logs, I'd like to separate them into two files, one contains JSON logs only and the other contains non-JSON logs, I get some ideas from [this](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/884#issuecomment-128439361) to extract JSON logs with `jq`, here are what I have tried using `tee` to split log into two files (usage from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28503/how-can-i-send-stdout-to-multiple-commands) & [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41246/how-to-redirect-output-to-multiple-log-files)) and `jq` to extract logs:

```
cat $logfile | tee  >(jq -R -c 'fromjson? | select(type == "object") | not') > $plain_log_file) >(jq -R -c 'fromjson? | select(type == "object")' > $json_log_file)
```

This extracts JSON logs correctly but returns `false` for each non-JSON log instead of the log content itself.

```
cat $logfile | tee  >(jq -R -c 'try fromjson catch .') > $plain_log_file) >(jq -R -c 'fromjson? | select(type == "object")' > $json_log_file)
```

this gets jq syntax error "catch ."

I do this so I can view the logs in [lnav](https://github.com/tstack/lnav) (an excellent log view/navigation tool).

Any suggestion on how to achieve this? Appreciate your help!

sample input:

```
{ "name": "joe"}
text line, this can be multi-line too
{ "xyz": 123 }
```

Comment: That's a [useless `cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat)

Comment: Do you really need a json parser for this? Wouldn't `grep '^{'` suffice to extract JSON lines?

Comment: @oguzismail I already tried `grep '^{` but it does not handle some of the multiline non-JSON logs.

Comment: @tripleee my script can get input from stdin or a file, in the former case `$logfile = "-"`.

Comment: Then either explain that in the question itself, or remove this distraction. The lack of quoting is disturbing, too.

Comment: Okay, consider including an excerpt from your log file then

Comment: added sample input.

Comment: I'm afraid this won't be possible if there are multiline JSON strings. There's no way to detect them with jq, because with `-R` each line is parsed as single string. Without `-R`, you have invalid JSON entities (the freeform text between JSON objects). Can you provide sample input with multiline log entries? With the input currently given, the solution is a trivial `grep '^{'`. Please make sure the sample accurately reflects the problem

Answer (score 1):

Assuming each JSON log item occurs on a separate line:

For the JSON logs:

```
jq -nR -c 'inputs|fromjson?'
```

For the others, you could use:

```
jq -nRr  'inputs | . as $in | try (fromjson|empty) catch $in'
```

Comment: This works exactly as expected, thanks! also will learn jq `assignment`.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to linewise separate the input into different files, go with @peak's solution. But if you want to further process the lines on conditions, you could turn them into an array using `-Rn` and `[inputs]`, and go from there. For instance, if you need the according line numbers (e.g. to feed them into another tool, e.g. `sed`), use `from_entries` which for arrays provides them in the `.key` field:

```bash
jq -Rn 'reduce ([inputs] | to_entries[]) as $in ({};
  .[($in.value | fromjson? | "json") // "plain"] += [$in.key]
)'
```

```json
{
  "json": [
    0,
    2
  ],
  "plain": [
    1
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/FF_IoNawfrd)

Answer (score 1):

If each JSON log entry can be spread over multiple lines, then some assumptions about the non-JSON log entries must be made.  Here is an example based on reasonable assumptions about the non-JSON entries.  A bash or bash-like environment is also assumed for the sake of convenience.

```
function log {
    cat<<EOF
{ "name": 
 "joe"}
text line, this can be 
multi-line too
{ 
"xyz": 123 }
EOF
}

log | sed '/^[^"{[ ]/ { s/"/\\"/g ; s/^/"/; s/$/"/;}' |
    tee >(jq -rc 'select(type == "string")' > strings.log) |
    jq -rc 'select(type != "string")' > json.log
```

Comment: I see you turned the plain text into strings which `jq` can handle,  very good idea! Yes, it's tricky to cover everything plain text can include, but what you have suggested here is good for many cases. thanks!